# How to set a content security policy for HTML attributes

Tags: node.js, hash, attributes, content-security-policy, nonce

I'm using node.js, and I would like to set a CSP for certain things, such as JavaScript and CSS. I could use nonces and hashes, but how would I allow an HTML attribute, such as:

```html
<div style="color:blue;" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
```

Since both of these are either CSS or JavaScript, my CSP blocks them. What can I do? I don't want to implement `unsafe-inline`.

Comment: You can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src).

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara so you're saying that there isn't an option to do what I want here.

Comment: Yes, this is being specified in MDN-web docs. May be there is some trick to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`'unsafe-hashes'` token was intended in CSP spec for HTML attributes. But it still is [not supported](https://csplite.com/csp/test173/#bug_Safari_unsafe-hashes) in Safari.

Therefore you have a lot of programmer's opts whose depends how deeply you are ready to rewrite code:

1. Do intercept the finished HTML code on the server before sending it to the browser, to pull out the `style='...'` and `onclick='...'` constructs, and to replace them with safe constructs (classes for styles and `addEventListeners()` for scripts).
   May be NodeJS has some useful plugins for that.
2. With styles you can replace `style="color:blue;"` to `data-style="color:blue;"` and
   handle all of these by script like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67339842/using-webp-fallback-with-csp/67345735#67345735).
   Just adapt it accordingly and use safe constructs like `el.style.backgroundColor = ...` but not unsafe `Element.setAttribute(style)`.
3. For inline event handlers you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318767/best-practice-for-removing-unsafe-inline-code-from-elements-to-seperate-script/67319146#67319146) techique (it's for jQuery, rewrite it to use addEventListeners).
4. Totally rewrite code with best practice - separate markup and datas.

   Move all `style="color:blue;"` into classes (class='blueColor'`). You can assign classes names like 'color-blue', 'display-hidden' etc. for ease of understanding.
   Replace all inline event handlers by [addEventListener()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) in a separate script.